# how to set a particular cell value in a row of a datagrid

Tags: wpf

how to set a particular cell value in a row of a datagrid using wpf.
How can i Add a value to particular cell programmatically

```
(datagridview.selecteditem.selectedcells[0]).content="new content";
```

Can I do something like this ?

I am binding data using a class

Comment: depends how you bind data to your collection ?

Comment: binding using a class  ? can we have some code please ?